# How to use constraintlayout to animate new intent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I start using a ConstraintLayout. I create some nice animation. So I have 2 xml layouts - beginning and end. I want to start it on start new activity. How to do this the best?

In short when i had to put this code:

```
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(_layout, transition);
            _set2.applyTo(_layout);
```

I'll try to put it inside method onCreate(...) and onResume(...) but when I start new activity (by Intnet) only a end layout was appear - without any animation.

The only way how it works is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    ...
    animate();
}

public void animate(){

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
            transition .setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
            transition .setDuration(1000);
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(_layout, transition);
            _set2.applyTo(_layout);


        }
    }, 500);
}
```

but I'm not sure that is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can start the animation as soon as the `Activity` gets focus. Try using `onWindowFocusChanged` like this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus) {
        ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
        transition.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
        transition.setDuration(1000);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(_layout, transition);
        _set2.applyTo(_layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I think it's also a bit too late. I have 3 layouts. Beginig - step1 - End. And in my option (with handler delay) I can see two animation (between beginning to step1 and between step1 to end). When I start using your ide there is only 1 animation - between beginning and end :(